# Expired US Visa Faded/Marked

Tags: visas, usa, passports

Does it matter during immigration (in India while leaving for the US or at the US CBP) if an expired US stamp is faded or marked while the valid visa is in pristine condition in the Passport.
The old visa expired in 2018 which is fading a bit and has a pen mark, but the new visa valid till 2021 is in pristine condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nobody at the US border is going to care much about your old and expired visa. After all it is old and expired. US CBP is only going to look at your current visa, and the same for the airline.

India probably isn't even going to care unless you have an ECR passport, but again only your current visa is of any importance, and it's not for a GCC country anyway.

Comment: This holds true as long as it is identifiable, if not it might be a problem cause it could be previewed to be a stamp from a country that would restrict entry to the US

Comment: @MattDouhan I'm having trouble imagining any damage that might cause an old US visa to resemble anything that might cause someone to be refused entry to the US, that also would not make the passport itself unusable.

Comment: Coffee stain or x stain I suppose that ruins that single page.

Comment: Actually a US CA DMV agent asked to strike off the old visa with a pen. And panicked I tried to erase the pen mark after I came home which led to a bit of fading.
The damage is very minimal but was just concerned. And yes its clearly visible as a US visa still.

Comment: @jacktraven It's common in other countries for border officers to draw a line across a used _single entry_ visa when the traveler enters the country. There is nothing common at all about a DMV employee drawing a line across a visa! But again, it's expired so in the end it really doesn't matter.

Comment: Thank you @Michael Hampton. Much relieved now knowing that travel should not be an issue. I was worrying myself crazy thinking if I need to reapply for a new visa when I visit India. But it did not make sense to me since the Valid visa(till 2021) is in pristine condition, only the expired one is a bit faded and has a  pen mark diagonally.

Comment: @Michael Hampton, I had a follow up question, will the US Consulate question the damage in the next Visa renewal in 2021? Since I always do a drop box option for my Visa category at Mumbai Consulate. One Note:: all Visas are on old Passport, and I have since procured a new one. Thank you

Comment: @jacktraven I think it very unlikely. Again, it's expired.